# TensorFlow Estimators and heavy pre-trained models: re-use across calls?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to use transfer learning off a pre-trained model in TensorFlow - with the Estimator API. The details of the model (number of layers, neurons, etc) will change and aren't relevant.

get_feature_extractor() instantiates a TensorFlow Hub module. What ends up happening is that every call to .train_and_evaluate(), .predict(), etc will blow away the session and the graph and start from scratch, reloading the feature extractor. This takes a few seconds. Is there a clean way to persist the results of get_feature_extractor() across these calls and make it hold on to the session - at least for .predict()? Or will I have to use a lower-level API to achieve this?

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    feature_extractor = get_feature_extractor()
    layer = feature_extractor(features)
    layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer)
    layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer, units=1280, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer, units=2048, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer, units=2)
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        estimator = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=layer)     
    else:
        accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels,
                               predictions=layer,
                               name='acc_op')
        metrics = {'accuracy': accuracy}
        loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=labels, predictions=layer)
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        estimator = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
            mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op,
            eval_metric_ops=metrics)    
    return estimator
```

Comment: Looks like a general question / feature request for Estimators, and avoiding repeated session initialization from a checkpoint. For TensorFlow Hub, there is no special provision, sorry. Looking at the code of Estimator.predict(), I don't see much there either for interactive use. But of course there is http://tensorflow.org/serving, if that is your use-case.

Comment: The only thing that makes TensorFlow Hub special in this case is that the models you get out of it tend to be very big (at least compared to anything I've trained on my own so far). I would have had the same problem had I trained, say Inception, on ImageNet myself.